# Allow other machines in the same network to connect with docker-compose container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have configured my docker container with this tutorial:
https://github.com/maxpou/docker-symfony

I can access to that page by visiting http://symfony.dev. Now I would like to share that site and visit that page from other PC in the same local network.

If I type my PC's IP in the browser URL I'm getting welcome page from nginx, but can't view my page.

Comment: Are you typing in the port address also while giving your PC's IP address?

Comment: I have tried various ports, but wihtout success. If I type `http://192.168.1.105` on my PC, I'm getting nginx's welcome page. If I type `http://symfony.dev` in the url, then the page loads. Now need to get somehow that "symfodny.dev" url on the 2nd pc...

Comment: I think its because of `server_name symfony.dev;
    root /var/www/symfony/web;` in https://github.com/maxpou/docker-symfony/blob/master/nginx/symfony.conf. You can edit your `etc/hosts` with 192.168.1.105 `symfony.dev` on your second PC.

Comment: Yes, thank. I've just changed `server_name symfony.dev` to `server_name 192.168.1.105` re-build container and it worked!